# rails: javascript/jQuery callbacks are triggered twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

Rails version 5.1.3

Specifically, it's the code in `assets/javascripts/channels/my_channel.coffee` where channel js client code lives, with other general js code. I'm using actioncable. But general jQuery/javascript callbacks suffer from this, too. Rewriting jQuery `append` in javascript didn't make difference.

All the callbacks are triggered twice. In other words, the fucntions to be executed after callbacks are triggered are called twice, including channel subscription and `$(document).ready`. Concretely, if I put

```
$(some_id_name).append some_string
```

In the event function in `$(document).ready`, it will be appended twice. I consider actioncable channel subscription instance as a callback, too. The `receive` method is called by user sending messages to trigger the instance. So the code in that method is executed twice, too. `append` in my case.

Could be entire js file is loaded twice. But how?

This only happens in test and production environment(Heroku), not in development environment. Implies anything?

I removed `turbolinks` cleanly in 3 steps as you can find by searching online. Include `jquery` and `rails-ujs` exactly once, no `jquery_ujs`, in `application.js`. No `public/assets` exists.

Part of `my_channel.coffee` looks like the following. All custom functions contain several callbacks like `click`, `keydown`. If I use `unbind` and `bind` to them **it will solve the problem**. But I can't apply this to `$(document).ready` and channel subscription instance.

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#messages').append "document is ready"
  submitQuestion()
  submitAnswer()
  hideJudgeForm()
  return
```

In `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require rails-ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require spin.js/spin
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Can you make sure that the files are not being included twice in the final HTML generated? In practice, can you press F12 in the browser and analyze it?

Comment: @AndréGuimarãesSakata Yes I double checked `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>` in `application.html.erb` and nowhere else should have it. Sorry I'm not sure how to analyze double loading  in browser console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the very first thing I would do is to check that I don't have any other file including the file `my_channel.coffee`. Neither as part of another bundle nor with `javascript_include_tag`.

After that, I would try removing the `require_tree .` in all my files and replace it with the specific list of files that I want Rails to load as part of the bundle. You might have two different files importing `my_channel.coffee` indirectly because of this.

Comment: removing `require_tree .` actually works. Currently I hold the opinion that `require_tree folder` requires both `my_channel.coffee` and `my_channel.js` in folder `channels`. I thought assets pipeline didn't include coffee files. Or does it? Who can confirm? Anyway, by requiring only js files it works.

Comment: Also for what reason development env doesn't suffer from this? If it's bc it doesn't use precompile then how it accesses `my_channel.coffee` or `my_channel.js`.

Comment: Sorry I cannot give you a proper answer, last time I used Rails it was in version 4. But back in my time I never used a `.coffee` extension directly. I would name my files something like `my_channel.js.coffee.erb` (the `erb` part can be omitted if you don't need any Rails helper) so that the Assets pipeline would parse the file first as an ERB, then as a coffee and lastly as a JS. In your case, you are probably creating, indirectly, two `my_channel.js`: one because you already created an actual `my_channel.js` file and the other because of the compilation of `my_channel.coffee`

Comment: Good enough. It is a plugin I use which compile coffee on save. I thought it was rails doing so I assumed coffee wouldn't be compiled.